# Copy contacts from Samsung device to other brand

Tags: contacts, samsung-kies, data-transfer

I have bought a brand new Gionee E6. First thing I need to do is copy contacts from my Samsung Galaxy phone to Gionee E6. I have backed up my contacts as `.spb` file using Kies. But when I try to import this contacts to Gmail/to my phone, it says *"File format is not supported"*.

I have tried the following in Kies:

1. Open `.spb` file and save it as `.cvs`/`.vcf`. The "Save As..." option just does not work
2. Tried to import the `.spb` file to `Google Contacts`, doesn't work either.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using proprietary vendor-software such as Kies for backups usually jails you into that eco-system. If your *Galaxy* is still available, up, and running, rather use the following steps to transfer your contacts:

1. open the *Contacts* app
2. hit the <kbd>menu</kbd> button
3. select "Import/Export"
4. chose to export your contacts to SDCard (will store in `.vcf` format)

Now you've got a decent backup which should restore on *any* Android device (at the same place in *Contacts*), and even most other systems, as VCF is a standard format ([VCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard)).

Alternatively, you can also sync all your contacts with your Google account from your old phone. They should automatically sync to all your other Android devices using the same account then.

Answer (score 0):

In Kies, open the `.spb` file, select all the contacts then save as `.vcf`. Then send to your phone via Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

1. From Windows, open Start menu, type `.vcf`, but don't hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> key
2. Let it find the file, right click any .vcf file, then select "Open file location"
3. Copy the file, attach the USB to the phone, paste to internal storage on phone (I made a folder called `/vcf`)
4. Download app called [Import Contacts (old)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.waxworlds.edam.importcontacts), then import from single .vcf card
5. Download [DW Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dw.contacts&hl=en) (paid app) to display and call.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have your Samsung phone than install [SYNCit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lenovo.leos.cloud.sync.row) application by Lenovo Group.

1. Create an account and sync your  contacts, SMS and other data.
2. Install the same app on your new mobile and sync it again.

Hassle free way to do it.